# do some work when user login or register in drupal6

Tags: 6, hooks

I want to set some fields in database when user registers or login. I know I don't have to change the drupal core and I guess I should use hooks for this purpose but I don't know how and where.

Should I write a new module and implement a hook inside it? What hook?

Comment: Best practices - [__NEVER HACK CORE__](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In drupal 6, there is a function named [hook_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_user/6).

By using this hook in your custom module. You can do watever you want. Remember to put condition in this by '$op' like

```
function hook_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  if($op == 'login') {
    //do watever you want
  }
}
```